# Gevent monkey unpatch

Tags: python, monkeypatching, gevent

I'm doing my program in many steps. One of them is to use gevent + monkey patch

```
from gevent import monkey; monkey.patch_all()
```

Everything works great. But can i unpatch it after i'm done using it ? I want to return to my default socket functions.

Comment: There is a write up of the solution here: http://emptysquare.net/blog/undoing-gevents-monkey-patching/

Comment: @Trevor that looks like a pretty good answer — why not add it as an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
reload(socket)
```

This blog post has a pretty good write up of the solution here: https://emptysqua.re/blog/undoing-gevents-monkey-patching/

Comment: what are the imports for reload and socket