# Python unit testing: How to stop gevent.monkey.patch_all() affecting asyncio tests?

Tags: python-asyncio, python-unittest, gevent, monkeypatching

We have a python test suite that tests code that uses `gevent.monkey.patch_all()`. The tests run fine.

In the same code base we have an alternative entrypoint that uses `asyncio`. There are also tests for this, which run fine on their own, with this kind of setup:

```
import asyncio
from our_module import main

class AsyncioTests(unittest.TestCase):
    """Test some asyncio stuff."""
    
    def test_something(self):
        asyncio.run(main())
```

However, if they run after the tests that import the module with the monkey patching, they hang forever. It seems to be **because** of the monkey patching.

Is there a way to stop this, by reversing the monkey patching?

Answer (score 0):

I found this https://emptysqua.re/blog/undoing-gevents-monkey-patching/ via [Gevent monkey unpatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10990151/gevent-monkey-unpatch) but the suggestion didn't work. Seemingly the problem is a bit deeper than the one module, perhaps specifically related to asyncio, (I also tried reloading several).

However, there is an [undocumented but public variable](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/21.1.2/src/gevent/monkey.py#L202) in the `gevent.monkey` module called `saved`:

```
# maps module name -> {attribute name: original item}
# e.g. "time" -> {"sleep": built-in function sleep}
# NOT A PUBLIC API. However, third-party monkey-patchers may be using
# it? TODO: Provide better API for them.
saved = {}
```

Using this, I could undo all the patches that `gevent` introduced in the `tearDownClass` of the test suite that uses that code:

```
class SomeTests(unittest.TestCase):
    """Tests using code imported from a module gevent.monkey.patch_all'd."""

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        """Undo monkeypatching so that other tests don't get stuck.

        Note: this is needed because of asyncio.
        """
        import importlib
        from gevent import monkey
        for modname in monkey.saved.keys():
            try:
                mod = __import__(modname)
                importlib.reload(mod)
                for key in monkey.saved[modname].keys():
                    setattr(mod, key, monkey.saved[modname][key])
            except ImportError:
                pass
```

Pretty horrid...? Maybe...